# How to correctly rollback commit with Solr's DirectUpdateHandler2?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

In Solr 5.5 (launched in embedded mode) I'm creating some bunch of documents, commit them and then I'm trying to rollback my last commit. Here is what I'm calling in my code:

```
UpdateHandler updateHandler = core.getUpdateHandler()
... // some docs
UpdateHandler#addDoc
UpdateHandler#commit
```

Check the index - everything is ok, index contains all docs.

But when I call `UpdateHandler#rollback` and check the index - nothing get changed...

what is the problem ? should I commit after rollback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr commits doesn't work that way. A commit writes *pending* documents to the index. A rollback drops the *pending* documents since the last commit instead of committing them. A rollback does not undo the last commit.

As soon as you commit you're saying "this is it, let's go", and Solr updates the index and makes the new documents searchable.

This is, as far as I know, how commits and rollbacks work in most RDBMSs as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Finally I have read the javadoc :) 

But, anyway, how to delete the last commit? How this code will look like?

Comment: You can't delete the last commit. There is no such thing. If you want to avoid doing the commit and just throw away the documents you've added (and not committed), you can issue a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your last commit programmatically at least in the cases in which it is feasible. So if you just inserted a doc with the unique id 1234567 then delete documents with that id. Not a great solution but I'm having issues finding better. Let me know if you find something my friend